# How to simulate TAB key press in Silverlight when user presses ENTER with MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, key, mvvm-light, keypress, simulate

How would you simulate a key press in MVVM in a Silverlight project?

I want to simualte the TAB key press when user presses ENTER, so it moves to the next textbox

Comment: can't you rely on commanding instead of simulating keypress ? what is actually your requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply handle the [`KeyUp` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keyup.aspx) where you can check which key is pressed.
Then, call the [Focus method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.focus.aspx) of the next control.
Do not forget to set the [Handled property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) to `true`.

Sample code :

```
// Handler for TextBox1
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        TextBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

You may also consider iterating over all controls, to find the next focusable element, using [TabIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You can even wrap everything in a attachable behavior, in order to simplify the wiring up.

Comment: Good solution, but I use MVVM. I want to avoid to hardcode code to UI elements by all means.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with that last comment

Comment: EventToCommand is a behavior that can fire an ICommand when a specific event occur. EX: The KeyDown event can fire the KeyInputCOmmand of your VM. take a look in this article : http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a926e36786ed#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET35%29%2fCommand%2fEventToCommand.cs

Comment: I still don't understant how will this make me move to the next textbox. Calling a command in my view model doesn't solve anything, I still have to hardcode names in xaml for each textbox...

Comment: Question related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354903/auto-tab-in-silverlight-3#_=_. I've found a simple solution, here: https://gist.github.com/4576803

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to achieve here? If you are just trying execute the same code that would be executed when a key is pressed, then just structure your code to allow this!

For automation of UI controls, simulating key and mouse events, see MSDN:

[UI Automation of a Silverlight Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645045%28VS.95%29.aspx)